# Obtaining WSDL from a Web Service Endpoint Address

Tags: wsdl, service

Is there a generic way of obtaining the service WSDL by using the service endpoint address. I know this can be done by appending ?wsdl to Axis2 services. But does this property hold for other web service containers as well?

Answer (score 6):

?wsdl works for all web services. So you can follow it.